# Where clause to restrict rows which are fully matched, show rows which are partially matched

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have the following SQL query:

```
    SELECT 
        job.EngineeringJobNumber, 
        CASE 
           WHEN line.PMVoucherNumber IS NULL THEN 0 
                                             ELSE 1 
        END AS JobLinesMatched
    FROM 
        Request_HDR hdr
    JOIN 
        Request_LINE line ON hdr.RequestId = line.RequestId
    JOIN 
        EngineeringJob job ON hdr.EngineeringJobId = job.EngineeringJobId
    JOIN 
        GL00105 gl ON line.AccountIndex = gl.ACTINDX
    WHERE 
        line.VendorID = 'Vendor' AND job.ApprovalStatus = 5
```

Which returns this:

| EngineeringJobNumber | JobLinesMatched |
| --- | --- |
| JOB00023 | 0 |
| JOB00023 | 0 |
| JOB00023 | 1 |
| JOB00023 | 0 |
| JOB00023 | 0 |
| JOB00011 | 1 |
| JOB00011 | 1 |
| JOB00011 | 1 |
| JOB00011 | 1 |
| JOB00011 | 1 |

What I'm trying to achieve is to restrict rows where the job lines are fully matched, i.e. all rows for that job are 1.

EDIT: I still need to be able view all the rows for a job which is not fully matched, i.e. all 5 rows for JOB0023.

I'm thinking I possibly need a HAVING clause perhaps? Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you please share sample data?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I'm a bit lost.  Why do you want to return two columns that have the same values in all the rows?  And your edit just thoroughly confuses the question,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `analytical function` as follows:

```
select EngineeringJobNumber, JobLinesMatched from
(SELECT job.EngineeringJobNumber,
        CASE WHEN line.PMVoucherNumber IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS JobLinesMatched
        count(CASE WHEN line.PMVoucherNumber is NULL then 0 END) 
            over (partition by job.EngineeringJobNumber) as sm
    FROM Request_HDR hdr
    JOIN Request_LINE line ON hdr.RequestId = line.RequestId
    JOIN EngineeringJob job ON hdr.EngineeringJobId = job.EngineeringJobId
    JOIN GL00105 gl ON line.AccountIndex = gl.ACTINDX
    WHERE line.VendorID = 'Vendor' AND job.ApprovalStatus = 5) t
 WHERE sm > 0
```

Comment: Just edited my question as I still need to return all rows for the job that isn't fully matched, including the matched one. But that gets me closer.

Comment: Updated the answer. Check now

Comment: Thanks @Popeye, that did the trick! Now I'm off to read up on PARTITION...